# cant access Jenkins user root access. in ubuntu18.04

Tags: ubuntu, root, user, jenkins

I changed `/etc/sudoers`:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
jenkins ALL= (ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

It works in root user but the mount command does not work in jenkins user in:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.0.85/user /root/test_dir  -o username=XXXXX,password=XXXX
```

The error is:

> mount: only root can use "--options" option

I check sudo also but still showing.
What happens?

Answer (score -1):

type "sudo su" without quotations, press enter and type your username password.

Then it will run user on which you are logged in as root